# I want to convert json string to C# array

Tags: c#, json

My model

```
public class Questions
{
    public string Question { get; set; }

    public string[] Options { get; set; }
}
```

My Controller method to create paper

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        var resolveRequest = HttpContext.Request;
        resolveRequest.InputStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        string jsonString = new StreamReader(resolveRequest.InputStream).ReadToEnd();
        var dist = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(jsonString);
        string[] result = dist.Select(kv => kv.Value.ToString()).ToArray();
        var conn = new MongoClient(Settings.Default.ConnectionStringSetting);
       var server = conn.GetServer();
        mongodb = server.GetDatabase(Settings.Default.DbMongoName);
        var collection = mongodb.GetCollection<MultiChoice>("MultiChoice");
        collection.Update(Query<PaperDetail>.EQ(s => s.paperName, "sam"), Update<MultiChoice>.AddToSet(s => s.questions, new Questions { Question = "Some question", Options = result }));
        return RedirectToAction("MultipleChoice");
    }
```

I want to convert my json string to string array and pass all data to "string[] Options"

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @Arijoon There is none :D at least, not that I can see...

Comment: how to deserialize the json array to c# string array??

Comment: What is the error you get?

Answer (score 0):

The way you are trying to generate a multiple choice with like code that and then trying to convert the json string back, not at all the way `ASP.Net MVC` or `WebAPI` would like you to do. There are very very simple and easy way to do this. The best approach would be -

1. Render the view with an Editor Template
2. Use form post to post directly and use the default ModelBinder to bind it for you . You will get the object directly. MVC will convert it for you.

Try this article -

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd405231(v=vs.98).aspx

**EDIT** :

Use something like this -

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Questions model)
{
}
```

but to make this work you have to use a view similar to this -

```
@model Questions
......

@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", ..., FormMethod.Post,..)
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Question)

    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Options, Model.Options.Select(x => new SelectListItem() { Text = x Value = x }))
```

Comment: Please  tell me how can I get all the values from the json string to an array..??

Comment: I already did, but you seem just need the solution, do not want to learn this. Not good for long run. Anyway, check the edit.